# How to set the data can do the increment?

Tags: php, sql, auto-increment

May I know how to set the $n variable once I insert the data, $n will plus 1 to previous my insert number?

For similar example what I've tried:

```html
$n = "AB000";
for ($n = 0; $n <= 0; $n++) 
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO [tablename] (user, country, batch_number) VALUES ('$user', '$country', $n)";
   // execute query
}
```

I want the expect result can like below the table, every time I do the insert function, the batch number can auto add 1:

```html
user | country| batch_number
John   USA        AB009
Lawn   Germany    AB010
Shawn  England    AB011
```

Hope someone can guide me how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using for the for loop? It might help to tag the question with that to get some more visibility.

Comment: PHP language I using

Comment: A couple of things - your loop is set to run till `$n <= 0`?  Also as it's string, you probably need quotes round it in `('$user', '$country', $n)` (although you should use prepared statements).

Comment: Yes. How to set every time I do the insert function can plus 1?

Comment: If you sorted your loop out, it would already do it, try `$n = "AB000";

echo $n.PHP_EOL;
$n++;
echo $n;`  The `$n++` will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you think about this script.

This is a different approch to acheive

online fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/569b6458b3080b4fa5c5f3d96bd0839334b02e8b

```
<?php
$n = "A00";
$user = "userName";
$country = "country";
for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $batch = "";
  $batch = $n."".$i;
  echo "INSERT INTO tablename (user, country, batch_number) VALUE "."('".$user."', '".$country."', $batch)";
  echo "\n";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `get_batch_number` function which needs:

- `$number` (in your case `$n`)
- `$prefix` (in your case 'AB')
- `$pad_length` (in your case 3)

```
for ($n = 0; $n <= $max_n; $n++) {
  $batch_number = get_batch_number($n, 'AB', 3);
  // ...
}
function get_batch_number($number, $prefix, $pad_length) {
  return $prefix . str_pad($number, $pad_length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```